# Quick Programming Check/Review

Tags: programming, code-review

I've been racking my head trying to start programming in a library organized method. My code works, but the translation and split to a .h and .cpp file is riddled with errors.

It's gotta be stupidly simple all I'm asking for is a review:

Header File

```
# ifndef _INITIALIZE_H
#define _INITIALIZE_H

#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
# include <Arduino.h>
#else
# include <WProgram.h>
#endif

//-Extra Includes-
#include <config.h> //Provides baud...
#include <SSC32.h>

#define STANDARD 0
#define DEBUG    1
#define VIRTUAL  2

class Initialize {
    private:
        int _mode;
    public:
        Initialize();
        void begin();

};

#endif
```

associated .cpp file:

```
//Comments
#include <Initialize.h>
SSC32 SSC;

Initialize::Initialize() 
{
    _mode = STANDARD;
}

void Initialize::begin() 
{
    SSC.begin(baud);
    if(Serial.available() > 0){
        if(sscReturn == 1){
            Serial.println("ver");
        }
    }
}
```

The error from the compiler:

```
D:\Github\Project-Onyx-Quadruped\code\HostControllerFirmware\Onyx-HostFirmware-Initial-7-2-15\libraries\Initialize\Initialize.cpp: In member function 'void Initialize::begin()':
D:\Github\Project-Onyx-Quadruped\code\HostControllerFirmware\Onyx-HostFirmware-Initial-7-2-15\libraries\Initialize\Initialize.cpp:9:12: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
D:\Github\Project-Onyx-Quadruped\code\HostControllerFirmware\Onyx-HostFirmware-Initial-7-2-15\libraries\Initialize\Initialize.cpp:9:16: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
D:\Github\Project-Onyx-Quadruped\code\HostControllerFirmware\Onyx-HostFirmware-Initial-7-2-15\libraries\Initialize\Initialize.cpp:9:16: error: expected ';' before ')' token
D:\Github\Project-Onyx-Quadruped\code\HostControllerFirmware\Onyx-HostFirmware-Initial-7-2-15\libraries\Initialize\Initialize.cpp:11:7: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
D:\Github\Project-Onyx-Quadruped\code\HostControllerFirmware\Onyx-HostFirmware-Initial-7-2-15\libraries\Initialize\Initialize.cpp:11:7: error: expected ')' before ';' token
D:\Github\Project-Onyx-Quadruped\code\HostControllerFirmware\Onyx-HostFirmware-Initial-7-2-15\libraries\Initialize\Initialize.cpp:11:17: error: expected primary-expression before '==' token
D:\Github\Project-Onyx-Quadruped\code\HostControllerFirmware\Onyx-HostFirmware-Initial-7-2-15\libraries\Initialize\Initialize.cpp:11:21: error: expected ';' before ')' token
Failed compiling libraries
```

Comment: What is sscReturn?

Comment: Where is sscReturn declared? This seems to be the (main) cause of the compiler errors.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, figured it out.

In the "config.h" file I was pulling, I had a
 `#define = 18;`

instead of a `#define 18`

I might be wrong, but the compiler stopped complaining

Comment: What are you defining as 18?

Comment: @user you cannot just type #define 18, it should be something like #define xyz 18. This means that from now on in your code xyz will be replaced by 18 (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Define)

Comment: `I might be wrong` - You **are** wrong. The line `#define 18` doesn't compile: `error: macro names must be identifiers`. This is not a helpful answer. I'm going to vote to close the question and the answer.